# Downloading and installing VIP7Kernel.dll on my pc

Tags: windows, dll, prolog

I have a VisualProlog program (exe executable) to run but when trying to execute the file windows (Seven in this case) tells me that he cannot find `VIP7Kernel.dll`.

I thought I could find this dll somewhere in the Internet but it is very hard. Where can I find it? And once I get it, how can I place it correctly in my Computer? Is it enough to place it in `System32` folder?

Thankyou

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: I do believe it is a programing issue after all... That is why I posted it here. I cannot run a prpgram compiled in visual-prolog, I assume that a pool of programmers and developers is needed to answer this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the person who gave you the program should have supplied the `VIP7Kernel.dll` file with it, so please ask them. When you've got it, *don't* install it in `System32`; that dir is for the OS to manage. Instead, put it in the same dir and the `.exe` file for the Prolog program
.